# Protect Code in ASP.NET 2.0 to authorized users with Two Factor Authentication (like Banks)

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-authentication, basic-authentication, asp.net-authorization

We are facing a situation where any help will be much appreciated.

**We use ASP.NET 2.0 Technology**

We have some webpages that are role-protected. So you need to authenticate with different credentials available( certificates, forms, etc) before entering on the app.
The problem comes that we need a second authentication factor like the one used on Banks( for example a SMS code or similar).
As a first approach we would like to protect only some fragments of code, but if that´s  not possible a possible solution would be to protect some complete webpages (to require this second authentication before executing).

1. Any suggestion of how this can be performed?
2. It´s possible to protect only fragments of code?

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Did you try googling for "asp.net two factor authentication" ? Even with ASP.NET Identity there is no magic involved, the programmer writes the pages for each step, the code that sends SMS and checks the results, transfers from one page to another etc.

Comment: But i want the second factor fires only when some code is executed, or some webpages, Not at the first Login only. Like the banks , you can login normally but when you want to operate a second factor is required. Thanks

Comment: As I said, did you try googling for this? There are a *lot* of answers that explain how to do it. Besides, what you are asking is *not* much different from sending an account activation code to a user in terms of the UI and ASP.NET pages required

Comment: Yes, but i think all responses are using ASP.NET MVC not ASP.NET 2.0 :(

Comment: You should still read them. As I said, there is no magic involved. The programmer has to write the pages and control the flow. The login page in ASP.NET 2 isn't provided out of the box, the programmer writes it and authenticates the user in the postback - you can modify your page to redirect to another page that will require the corred code before authenticating.